How to show the last page any user whatsoever has visited?
In my Drupal 10 project I want to create a view with just one result --- the last page that any user whatsoever has visited. How can this be done?
After enabling the core module Statistics I do get the latest viewed (node) filter criteria but I don't understand what to configure as an operator and a value for that filter criteria.

The Statistics module does not track when pages are visited, so you can't do what you ask.
Because of its low rate of use, the Statistics module has been removed from core as of Drupal 11.
As stated on the new contrib module page, the features are:

it only counts views of node in full page mode
it only maintains running grand total and daily subtotal of views, and no historical data

My emphasis above. As you can see, there is no historical information available for you to check the last page.
